# Power BI create 2 dropdown slicer on same table two columns

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I need to have 2 dropdown slicers, on the same table. For example, consider the following table:

| Country | State |
| --- | --- |
| India | PUNJAB |
| India | DELHI |
| USA | CALIFORNIA |
| USA | TEXAS |

I want the first slicer to show a single selection of Country as a dropdown and the second Slicer to show State based on Country. For example, if India is selected then the second slicer should be showing PUNJAB and DELHI.

How do I achieve this, currently if I select any state say PUNJAB, the country is also getting filtered and changed to INDIA and I am not able to select USA.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to [Edit interactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/service-reports-visual-interactions) under the Format pane and edit the second slicer to not cross-filter the first one.

Alternatively, you could use both in the same slicer as a hierarchy.

[image: Hierarchy Slicer Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks Alexis I am currently using the second way of using hierarchy, in the first method as I need to do single select I am not able to achieve the required results